# Returning ADO.Net query as JSON array from controller

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I have the following database class which uses ADO.NET to connect to a SQL database without any models. I use the GetData method to return a serialized json string which I then convert in the ActionResult get request in my controller a shown below. The issue is I am first returning a DataTable object from the ADO.NET query which is then serialized to a string using a third party nuget package Newtonsoft which is converted to a json/application type in my controller. Is there no way to achieve these results with less steps or third party plugins?

When using a model approach with the DB such as Entity Framework I was able to use Ok() method to convert to JSON format for my EF query. This was so simple but I hated the idea of keeping models that I will never use so I switched to ADO.NET. I am still learning both ADO.NET and ASP.NET Core so any help is appreciated.

Database class

```
        public String GetData(String connectionString, string str, params IDataParameter[] sqlParams)
        {
            int rows = -1;
            DataTable objResult = new DataTable();

            try
            {
                SqlDataReader myReader;

                using (SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    myCon.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(str, myCon))
                    {
                        if (sqlParams != null)
                        {
                            foreach (IDataParameter para in sqlParams)
                            {
                                myCommand.Parameters.Add(para);
                            }
                        } 

                        myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                        objResult.Load(myReader);

                        myReader.Close();
                        myCon.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objResult);

        }
```

Controller:

```
        public ActionResult DatatableLoad()
        {
            //Since ADO.NET returns a datatable we serialize it first in GetData()
            //We have parameters here just in case we want to use them
            string query = "select * from dbo.UserAccountsTbl WHERE USERNAME=@UserName;";

            var parameters = new IDataParameter[]
            {
                new SqlParameter("@UserName", "SB")
            };

            String jsonResult = db.GetData(connectionString, query, parameters);

            return Content(jsonResult, "application/json");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

To return the output of a query in JSON format you need to do this:

```
        return Json(jsonResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

jsonResult is the output list of the Executed Query.